# Typescript function returns partial only if parameter is partial

Tags: typescript

I have a function that for a given camelCase object returns the same object in snake_case

```
// Let's imagine these are the types
interface CamelData {
   exempleId: number
   myData:string
}

interface SnakeData {
   exemple_id: number
   my_data: string
}

export const camelToSnake = (
  camelData: Partial<CamelData>
): Partial<SnakeData> => {
  return {
    exemple_id: camelData.exempleId,
    my_data: camelData.myData
}
```

The thing is I want my function returning type to be SnakeData whenever camelData is of type CamelData.

Basically something that works like that

```
export const camelToSnake = (
  camelData: Partial<CamelData>
): if (camelData is of type CamelData) {SnakeData} else {Partial<SnakeData>} => {
  return {
    exemple_id: camelData.exempleId,
    my_data: camelData.myData
}
```

Can you help ?
Have a great day

Comment: Can you provide the `CamelData` and `SnakeData` types?

Comment: I'll update my question then

Comment: @RouckyKM Isn't it more like, the argument to `camelToSnake` can have any of the properties of `CamelData`, but the result, has to have the same props ?

Comment: Yeah kinda but it would be better if it can also spot if it's not Partial

Comment: There are quite a few possible approaches, so it depends on your use case.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6vdDw) for some options.   Let me know if you want to see any of those expanded into an answer.  (Please ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz your playground is very nice ! Could make an answer that combines Overload namespace and IndexedAccess namespace ?
(if it is possible to, I don't know if the overload will work with arrow function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question to share the solution I have chosen. Thank you guys for your helping comments and answers that helped me choosing this solution.

```
interface CamelData {
   exempleId: number
   myData:string
}

interface SnakeData {
   exemple_id: number
   my_data: string
}

type SnakeDataFor<T extends Partial<CamelData>> = {
    example_id: T['exampleId'];
    my_data: T['myData'];
}

export function camelToSnake(camelData: CamelData): SnakeData;
export function camelToSnake<T extends Partial<CamelData>>(
  camelData: T
): SnakeDataFor<typeof camelData>;
export function camelToSnake<T extends Partial<CamelData>>(
  camelData: T
): SnakeDataFor<typeof camelData> {
  return {
    exemple_id: camelData.exempleId,
    my_data: camelData.myData
  }
}
```

So basically this goes a little beyond of what I asked for at first.
It sends back `SnakeData` type if the parameter is of type `CamelData` but otherwise it sends back a custom type that has the same props as the parameter.

I'll keep this post updated if I find a better solution later on.

Comment: So I shouldn't post an answer, I guess?

Comment: @jcalz You may want to post your Conditional namespace, it might be useful ! Thank you once again for your playground it was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Function overloading:

```
export function camelToSnake (camelData: CamelData): SnakeData;
export function camelToSnake (camelData: Partial<CamelData>): Partial<SnakeData>;
export function camelToSnake (camelData: Partial<CamelData>): Partial<SnakeData> {
  return {
    exemple_id: camelData.exempleId,
    my_data: camelData.myData
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic type for the input and if it it extends `CamelData` then the return type is `SnakeData`, otherwise just use partials:

```
// Let's imagine these are the types
interface CamelData {
   exempleId: number
   myData:string
}

interface SnakeData {
   exemple_id: number
   my_data: string
}
// exported call signature is specified seperately so inside the function it just needs to typecheck to a partial
// you can just use one call signature but convincing typescript the data fits the type `T extends CamelData ? SnakeData : Partial<SnakeData>` without typecasts is hard.
export function camelToSnake<T extends Partial<CamelData>>(
  camelData: T
): T extends CamelData ? SnakeData : Partial<SnakeData>
export function camelToSnake(
  camelData: Partial<CamelData>
): Partial<SnakeData>{
  return {
    exemple_id: camelData.exempleId,
    my_data: camelData.myData
    }
}

const x = camelToSnake({exempleId:1})
//   ^? const x: Partial<SnakeData>
const y = camelToSnake({exempleId:2, myData: "hi"})
//   ^? const y: SnakeData
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-G92OZZqCoC5PP50Yyws1RVKG3mi2Wq3extNvgCHtkXvpVlt8cdzpLaGTgbL9oT+fZ4mFIVAFGaZDWrbkimUqhicWLQTV4T76g0ABpkilqGkfTmI2g1eYgtPnM4GFDJht5KAALwLwQms1uySjyKaLQARkc-qeYFkAD1GZvVrtRgfi8fG6fz6pLwATBOM5BDoABEBBIGBt73qEz4MEAA)

Here I used a single overload so that typescript doesn't try to typecheck inside the function for the conditional type since that'd be hard, to do it with arrow notation it'd be the only option though:

```
const camelToSnake = <T extends Partial<CamelData>>(
    camelData: T
):T extends CamelData ? SnakeData : Partial<SnakeData> => ({
    exemple_id: camelData.exempleId,
    my_data: camelData.myData
} as T extends CamelData ? SnakeData : Partial<SnakeData>)
```